# Upgrading to Cordova iOS 6 and changing config file, logs out users from my app

Tags: cordova, cookies, cordova-ios

I am updating my Cordova app to use Xcode 12 and cordova-ios 6.2.0.  As part of this I had to add to my config.xml file in the platform section:

```
 <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
```

to deal with CORS issues of accessing icons stored within my bundle.

I can access my icons fine now but when I simulate updating my app, my users are being logged out.

I believe this is a cookie issue, the upgraded app can't read the existing cookie.

Any ideas?  This would be pretty annoying for all my existing users.  There's no solution over in the Cordova discussion groups.  (I'm using cordova version 9.0.0.)

Thanks much!

- Jon

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I included the cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix plugin and do not add the lines

```
 <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
 <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

in my config.xml file.

With this, I can access icons in my bundle without a CORS issue.  And the best part is that it does not wipe out data previously stored on the phone - my users don't get logged out!

For more info:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/883

- Jon